# compute the limit of $xy(x+y-2)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches infinity for two domains

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Problem is to compute the limit of $xy(x+y-2)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches infinity for the domain

(a) $D_f=R^2$

(b)$D_f=\{(x,y): |y-x|<1, x,y>0\}$

For (a) I have found that when approaching infinity along the line $x=y$ we have that the values for the function goes to infinity. Along the $x$-axis the function becomes $0$ and therefor the limit becomes $0 $ as well. So for the first domain (which is all of the points in $R^2$ ) there exists no limit.

For (b) I am not sure how to approach the problem. I know that $|y-x|<1$ is the same as $-1<y-x <1$. The problem becomes reduced to only look at points in $R^2$ that satisfied that the distance between them are not more than 1, and are positive.

I am thinking that maybe it is possible to estimate the function to be less than another function of one variabel and somehow use the squeeze theorem. My problem is that I am no good at inequalities like that.

Comment: I tried bounty but just looking for some help

Comment: Should not both $x$ and $y$ tend to $\infty$? Perhaps you mean $x^2+y^2\to \infty$?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz you are right! I did not think about that. I have to ask my teacher about this.

Comment: I think you can still use the method used in part (a). Find two lines in your region such that the limits are different along both.

Comment: @Allawonder You really think that that is possible? Or are you arguing for $x^2 + y^2 \to \infty$ ? For $(x,y) \to (\infty,\infty)$ both cases should infinitely divergence, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @hal4math Of course the radius goes to infinity; as it also does in the first case (part (a)), so I don't think that tells us much about the behaviour of the function OP is interested in. So yes, I do think the limit does not exist even in case (b). It's just a hunch. I've not checked this out, and I might be mistaken.

Comment: @Allawonder I think the question that was raised by MostafaAyaz  is weather OP is asking $\lim_{x^2+y^2 \to \infty} xy(x+y-2)$ or $\lim_{(x,y) \to (\infty,\infty)} xy(x+y-2)$. I think for (b) it doesn't really make a different because both will "converge to infinity".

Comment: @hal4math There might have been a misunderstanding. My initial comment was for OP, not for Mostafa Ayaz.

Comment: I think when saying (x,y) --> ∞ in this assignment its the same as x^2+y^2 --> ∞

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

For $b)$, we must have at least one of the $x$ or $y$ tend to $\infty$. Because of symmetry assume $x\to \infty$. Now note that $$y>x-1$$so what is the lower bound of $xy(x+y-2)$ for sufficiently large $x$?

Comment: so  $xy(y+x-2) $ Can I write it as $xy(y+x-2)  > x(x-1)((x-1)+x-2) $ ? and the latter goes to infinity

Comment: If $(x,y)\to \infty$ means $x^2+y^2\to \infty$, then yes. You can conclude that

Comment: yes, could I say that since  (−1)((−1)+−2)<(+−2)<(+1)((+1)+−2) then by the squeeze theorem the function also goes to infinity? Did we use that x,y > 0 in this example ?

Comment: I used $x,x-1>0$ but the upper bound you obtained for the squeeze theorem has no practical importance since an upper bound that tends to $\infty$ does not end up with any result for the limit since $$\forall x\in\Bbb R\cup[-\infty,\infty]\implies x\le \infty$$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can taylor the following into something rigoros: Let's define $f(x,y) = xy$ and $g(x,y) = x+y-2$. You want to investigate $\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)} f(x,y)\cdot g(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \in D_f$. Now, notice since the distance of $x$ and $y$ only can be in magnitude of 1 and there are both positive numbers you know that 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)} g(x,y) = +\infty,$$ right? The same is true for
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)} f(x,y) = +\infty.$$ 
So you can conclude that also 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)} f(x,y)\cdot g(x,y) = +\infty,$$
where I used some rules for infinite limits.